# Can't get the list of worksheets in a workbook stored in sharepoint using microsoft-graph-api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, worksheet, microsoft-graph-files

I'm not able to get the list of worksheets in a workbook for some reason. this might be related to my other issue which is [can't add records in a excel table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64979775/error-when-adding-rows-to-a-sharepoint-excel-workbook-table-maxrequestdurationex?noredirect=1#comment114881185_64979775)

this is the full error message that is returned to me when calling this endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/OurSiteId/drives/OurDriveId/Items/OurFileId/workbook/worksheets

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MaxRequestDurationExceeded",
        "message": "We're sorry. We couldn't finish what you asked us to do because it was taking too long.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "gatewayTimeoutUncategorized",
            "message": "The service wasn't able to complete the request within the time limit.",
            "innerError": {
                "code": "MaxRequestDurationExceeded",
                "message": "We're sorry. We couldn't finish what you asked us to do because it was taking too long."
            },
            "date": "2020-11-24T12:55:28",
            "request-id": "c28bc40e-4ba6-4606-8c5a-ea0663cafa29",
            "client-request-id": "c28bc40e-4ba6-4606-8c5a-ea0663cafa29"
        }
    }
}
```

there appears to be a file size limit of a workbook as described here [file limit in sharepoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-size-limits-for-workbooks-in-sharepoint-9e5bc6f8-018f-415a-b890-5452687b325e) but still, the file that I am working is only 40mb (limit is 50mb) and I am already encountering access issues on the file.

The file that I am working already has more than a million records, is that possibly the cause of the issue?

Comment: It may be the case, but just make sure you can open the excel file in your browser/onedrive and you can write the info manually. As a rule of thumb make sure that it doesn't contain any styles, any empty cells/columns, any macro's etc.

Comment: Moving this to answer. So it can be useful to others. Consider upvoting it. If you have more questions or update, go ahead and ask it,

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case, but just make sure you can open the excel file in your browser/onedrive and you can write the info manually. As a rule of thumb make sure that it doesn't contain any styles, any empty cells/columns, any macro's etc